# concept of runanubandha

Tags: scripture, yoga, yoga-sutras

Runanubandha is the physical memory that a person carries within himself. I think most of the information about this issue is given by Jaggi Vasudev. I am intrigued by this topic and want to know in which scripture is this particular type of memory mentioned? What is the main purpose of washing runanubandha? Which is the best method of washing this type of memory?

Comment: Robert Svoboda's "Aghora III - The Law Of Karma" (ISBN: 9780914732372) was particularly useful in getting me started in terms of understanding concepts.